# passing parameter from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have written a code which sends a query to mysql database and then gets the results row by row using $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result).

I need to send the data for each row to a javascript function.

Here is the piece of code I used:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.'queryResults('. json_encode($row) . ');'.'</script>';

}
```

In my javascript function I have :

```
function queryResults(data){
var results = JSON.parse(data);}
```

However, I get error:

```
"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"
```

Where is the problem with my code?

Comment: It is literally impossible to day. Why don't you console.log(data) before calling JSON.parse() on it.

Comment: What is `data`? And do you really output tons of script tags?

Comment: You don't need `JSON.parse` here. Echoing JSON from PHP into JavaScript will just create an object literal in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSON](http://json.org/) directly inside a script tag is interpreted as a JavaScript [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) - you actually pass an object to the `queryResults` function. To use `JSON.parse()` (which you don't have to) you would need to wrap it inside JavaScript string delimiters and escape all quotes in the string returned by `json_encode`, so that JavaScript would see a valid string.

Btw, your sample function is missing the `data` parameter in its signature.

Comment: Ok. great! But how can i use it as a json string?  could you make an example of how to escape the quotes? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: It would look like `'var obj = JSON.parse( "'.addslashes(json_encode($row)).'");'`

Answer (score 0):

You need the field name of the table.

```
json_encode($row['fieldname'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have no parameter specified in the function signature. This may solve the issue:

```
function queryResults(data){
var results = JSON.parse(data);
}
```